# Connection refused while scraping npiprofile.com

Tags: python, web-scraping

using [jupyter-notebook](/questions/tagged/jupyter-notebook) I am trying to build a program that will go into this website "https://npiprofile.com/clia/" and input the CLIA ID from a [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) under the column name "CLIA Number". It will take the data in the cell of this column and then search it in the website. After this, a clickable link under NPI will pop up and I need the program to click on that. After this is done, it will need to collect:

"NPI", "Provider Name", "Location Address", "Classification", "Authorized Official Name", "Authorized Official Title", and "Authorized Official Phone"

The code runs but never opens the website to extract data like it does on previous attempts. I have around 20,000 clia numbers I have to extract

```
#import all files
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df = pd.read_csv('CLIA POL')
clia_numbers = df['CLIA Number']

base_url = 'https://npiprofile.com/clia/'

# Function to extract data from the NPI page
def extract_data(npi_soup):
    data = {}

    data['NPI'] = npi_soup.find('span', {'class': 'npi'}).text.strip()
    data['Provider Name'] = npi_soup.find('h1', {'class': 'name'}).text.strip()
    data['Location Address'] = npi_soup.find('div', {'class': 'location'}).find('p', {'class': 'address'}).text.strip()
    data['Classification'] = npi_soup.find('div', {'class': 'taxonomy'}).find('span', {'class': 'classification'}).text.strip()

    authorized_official = npi_soup.find('div', {'class': 'authorized-official'})
    data['Authorized Official Name'] = authorized_official.find('span', {'class': 'name'}).text.strip()
    data['Authorized Official Title'] = authorized_official.find('span', {'class': 'title'}).text.strip()
    data['Authorized Official Phone'] = authorized_official.find('span', {'class': 'phone'}).text.strip()

    return data


# Function to get the NPI page from the CLIA page
def get_npi_page(clia_number):
    url = base_url + clia_number

    response = requests.get(url, timeout=30)  # Increase the timeout duration
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    npi_link = soup.find('a', {'class': 'npi'})

    if npi_link:
        npi_url = npi_link['href']
        npi_response = requests.get(npi_url, timeout=30)  # Increase the timeout duration
        npi_soup = BeautifulSoup(npi_response.content, 'html.parser')

        return npi_soup
    else:
        return None


# Create an empty DataFrame to store the extracted data
data_columns = ['NPI', 'Provider Name', 'Location Address', 'Classification', 'Authorized Official Name', 'Authorized Official Title', 'Authorized Official Phone']
extracted_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=data_columns)

# Iterate through the CLIA numbers, get the NPI page, and extract the data
for clia_number in clia_numbers:
    npi_soup = get_npi_page(clia_number)

    if npi_soup:
        data = extract_data(npi_soup)
        extracted_data = extracted_data.append(data, ignore_index=True)

# Save the extracted data to a new CSV file
extracted_data.to_csv('extracted_data.csv', index=False)
```

The error message I get is as follows:

````
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    702             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 703             httplib_response = self._make_request(
    704                 conn,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    385         try:
--> 386             self._validate_conn(conn)
    387         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
   1041         if not getattr(conn, "sock", None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
-> 1042             conn.connect()
   1043 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    413 
--> 414         self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
    415             sock=conn,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir, key_password, ca_cert_data, tls_in_tls)
    448     if send_sni:
--> 449         ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
    450             sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname=server_hostname

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, ssl_context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
    492     if server_hostname:
--> 493         return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
    494     else:

~\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
    500         # ctx._wrap_socket()
--> 501         return self.sslsocket_class._create(
    502             sock=sock,

~\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py in _create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)
   1040                         raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
-> 1041                     self.do_handshake()
   1042             except (OSError, ValueError):

~\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py in do_handshake(self, block)
   1309                 self.settimeout(None)
-> 1310             self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   1311         finally:

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    488             if not chunked:
--> 489                 resp = conn.urlopen(
    490                     method=request.method,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    786 
--> 787             retries = retries.increment(
    788                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    549             if read is False or not self._is_method_retryable(method):
--> 550                 raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
    551             elif read is not None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    768             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 769                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    770             raise value

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    702             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 703             httplib_response = self._make_request(
    704                 conn,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    385         try:
--> 386             self._validate_conn(conn)
    387         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
   1041         if not getattr(conn, "sock", None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
-> 1042             conn.connect()
   1043 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    413 
--> 414         self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
    415             sock=conn,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir, key_password, ca_cert_data, tls_in_tls)
    448     if send_sni:
--> 449         ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
    450             sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname=server_hostname

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, ssl_context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
    492     if server_hostname:
--> 493         return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
    494     else:

~\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
    500         # ctx._wrap_socket()
--> 501         return self.sslsocket_class._create(
    502             sock=sock,

~\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py in _create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)
   1040                         raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
-> 1041                     self.do_handshake()
   1042             except (OSError, ValueError):

~\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py in do_handshake(self, block)
   1309                 self.settimeout(None)
-> 1310             self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   1311         finally:

ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_13720\1785300690.py in <module>
     39 # Iterate through the CLIA numbers, get the NPI page, and extract the data
     40 for clia_number in clia_numbers:
---> 41     npi_soup = get_npi_page(clia_number)
     42 `your text```your text``
     43     if npi_soup:

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_13720\1785300690.py in get_npi_page(clia_number)
     19     url = base_url + clia_number
     20 
---> 21     response = requests.get(url)
     22     soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
     23 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     71     """
     72 
---> 73     return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
     74 
     75 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     57     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     58     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 59         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     60 
     61 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    585         }
    586         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 587         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    588 
    589         return resp

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    699 
    700         # Send the request
--> 701         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    702 
    703         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    545 
    546         except (ProtocolError, OSError) as err:
--> 547             raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    548 
    549         except MaxRetryError as e:

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None))
````

I tried adding on waiting periods but it never fully works.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `User-Agent` header to get correct response from the server:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://npiprofile.com/clia"

clia_numbers = ["52D2072838", "24D1040592"] # <-- read clia numbers from the CSV file

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/111.0"
}

all_dfs = []
for n in clia_numbers:
    r = requests.get(url, params={"sSearch": n}, headers=headers).text
    # here handle exceptions as necessary:
    all_dfs.append(pd.read_html(r)[0])

final_df = pd.concat(all_dfs)
print(final_df)
```

Prints:

```
          NPI        CLIA                              Name          Type                     Taxonomy                                    Address           Phone
0  1487296307  52D2072838  EXACT SCIENCES LABORATORIES, LLC  Organization  Clinical Medical Laboratory        650 FORWARD DRIVE MADISON, WI 53711  (608) 284-5700
0  1114993136  24D1040592    MAYO CLINIC HOSPITAL-ROCHESTER  Organization                Clinic/Center  1705 SE BROADWAY AVE ALBERT LEA, MN 56007  (507) 373-2384
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, when I do this I get an error message stating that there are no tables found. I looked into it a little deeper and it says that:

"This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. The action you just performed triggered the security solution. There are several actions that could trigger this block including submitting a certain word or phrase, a SQL command or malformed data."

Is there a way to get around this? It mentions that I can email the site owner but not sure how practical that actually is.